# getting arguments of the decorated function in python

Tags: python, arguments, closures, decorator

How does the wrapper in a Python decorator reach the decorated function argument's?
For example:

```
def decorate(f):
    def wrapped_function(*args):
        print args
        f()
    return wrapped_function

@decorate
def my_function(*args):
    print("Hello world")

my_function("a")


# output
('a',)
Hello world
```

So, I know that wrapped_function is a closure,
because it retains access to my_function as variables from the upper scope.
But how could it bring it's arguments in theory?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Could you rephrase the question?

Comment: The closure is how it gets the `f`, but has nothing to do with the arguments. It gets those the same way as any other function—you call it, and the args you call it with get passed as its parameters. The question is how the original function `f` gets the arguments. In your example, it _doesn't_—if you want it to, you have to call `f(*args)`. (In your case, because it takes `*args` and never accesses them, you get away with it.)

Comment: Thanks, but i was seeking for answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
@decorate
def my_function(*args):
    pass
```

is essentially the same as this:

```
my_function = decorate(my_function)
```

Therefore, `wrapped_function` replaces `my_function`.

That means:

```
my_function("a")
```

actually does this:

```
wrapped_function("a")
```

So you hand in the argument to `wrapped_function` already.
You can see this looking at the attribute `__name__`

```
>>> my_function.__name__
'wrapped_function'
```

Without decoration `__name__` would be `my_function.`

Comment: That is exactly what i was looking for <br/> my_function("a") will be wrapped_function("a")<br/> Also, my_function and wrapped_function must have the same signature